# How get opacity param in rgba using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna know how i can get the opacity param using javascript / jQuery.

For exemple : rgba(255,255,255,0.5)

I need to get 0.5

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: The problem encounter is I really don't know how to get it :)

Comment: Maybe regex, I don't know, I would prefere a cleaner solution

Comment: rgba() is not well known fuction, what do you trying to get ?

Comment: you have a string  "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" ?

Comment: yes, .css('opacity') seems not working

Comment: @socrate, regular expressions are indeed appropriate here, try setting capture groups as explained [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Parentheses).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In case if "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" is string:

```
var rgba="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)";
var alpha=rgba.replace(/^.*,(.+)\)/,'$1')
```

Comment: I'll try it, give you a shoot

Comment: Just a question can you change this regex to match rgba with this type : 0.05 ?
Actually for rgba(255,255,255,0.01) that return me 0

Comment: works for me:
`var rgba="rgba(255,255,255,0.01)";
var alpha=rgba.replace(/^.*,(.+)\)/,'$1');
console.log(alpha);
0.01`

but you can make it string to be sure: 
`var alpha=rgba.replace(/^.*,(.+)\)/,'$1')+'';`

Answer (score 2):

try out this function [link](http://snipplr.com/view/60570/), it defines a function which returns the rgba colors in for of an object.